# Swashbuckle/swagger, change displayed doc via jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I need to change active doc displayed by swagger with Jquery.

Detail:
My routes are separated into groups/version, so average api call looks like this: Api/{group}/{version}/Controller/Method

And my swagger docs are generated that way aswell. But I dont really like the way user selects active doc inside the UI. So I just added my own javascript to insert some  inputs for this. What I dont know is hot to tell the swaggerUI to change to specific doc.

Here is my javascript:

```
(function (){
var DiscoveryUrlSelector = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function ()
    {
        // Nerenderuj opakovaně na reloadu
        var defaultVal = this.$el.val()
        if (!this.$el.find('#input_' + this.options.name).length) {

            var select = $('<select id="input_' + this.options.name + '" name="' + this.options.name + '"></select>');
            select
                .css('margin', '0px 10px 0px 0px')
                .css('border', '1px solid gray')
                .css('padding', '3px')
                .css('width', '100px')
                .css('font-size', '0.9em');

            _.each(this.options.discoveryPaths, function (path) {
                var option = $('<option>' + path + '</option>');
                select.append(option);
            });

            select.val(defaultVal);
            select.change(SetVersionedGroup);
            select.insertBefore('#input_username');
        }    
        return this;
    }
});

new DiscoveryUrlSelector(
    {
        el: $('#api_selector'),
        name: 'Group',
        rootUrl: swashbuckleConfig.rootUrl,
        discoveryPaths: Array.from(new Set(swashbuckleConfig.discoveryPaths.map(x => x.substring(13, x.lastIndexOf("v")))))
    }).render();

new DiscoveryUrlSelector(
    {
        el: $('#api_selector'),
        name: 'Version',
        rootUrl: swashbuckleConfig.rootUrl,
        discoveryPaths: Array.from(new Set(swashbuckleConfig.discoveryPaths.map(x => x.substring(x.lastIndexOf("v"), x.length))))
    }).render();

function SetVersionedGroup()
{


}
```

})();

And my Header looks like this:
[image]

Any ideas how to finish my SetVersionedGroup function?